# "We are American" or "We are Americans"? The singular vs. the plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which expression is more idiomatic or correct:

- We are American
- We are Americans

Should I use *American* in the singular or in the plural form? And why?

Comment: Yes. Use whichever one you meant to use. Someone will probably give you the grammatical explanation of why this is possible.

Comment: The first is an adjectival use of *American;* the second a substantive use.  Substantives are adjectives used as nouns.  Thus the phrases *I am Canadian* and *we are Canadian* use *Canadian* adjectivally (as an adjective), but *I am a Canadian* and *we are Canadians* use the word substantively (as a noun).

Comment: @user61979 is absolutely correct, and emphasises a very important point (that I was just about to emphasise, too). Just a small detail, though: a substantive is just _a noun_; it is not necessarily an adjective used as a noun specifically.

Comment: In this case the adjective is the same as the denonym, but that isn't always the case: *"we are American"* corresponds to *"we are Danish"*, while *"we are Americans"* corresponds to *"we are Danes"*. Both of these are fine; just don't say *"I am a Danish"*.

Answer (score 4):

You can virtually force one version or the other by context:

Are you Americans or Canadians? ...

Are you Canadian? ...

I don't think RyeɃreḁd's answer will really stand much scrutiny, though doubtless there are factors nudging one's choice one way or the other. And it is a choice:

> We are American / I am American

'American' here is a (proper) adjective; compare 'We are cold'. It has no 'plural form'.

> We are Americans / I am an American

'Americans' and 'American' here are proper nouns; compare 'We are doctors'.

An Ngram shows that both constructions are commonly used. But you wouldn't get many Brits, standing in a defined group of people or otherwise, volunteering 'We are Britons' / 'Englishmen'. 'We are British' / 'English' is the far more usual way of putting this (as further Ngrams illustrate).

Answer (score 1):

You would say "We are Americans" if you are standing in a defined group of people (can be counted) and talking about your group as individuals.

You would say "We are American" if talking about an abstract uncountable population or a group of people that will stay grouped.

> Usage:
>
> Going through customs with your family, you are asked "What
>   nationality are each of you?" Answer, "We are Americans."
>
> Person in a foreign country asks, "Is the new group of doctors from
>   the U.S. or Canada?" Answer, "We are American."